# Firebase rules to avoid Duplicate Entries

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

What are the firebase rules required to avoid duplicate entries in below users array at **sList** collection level

```
"sList" : {
    "-KZawgegLrIyq9h6GSf8" : {
      "name" : "Test",
      "users" : [ "-KZawhnFZLcqFKNwZnSi", "-KZawhnFZLcqFKNwZnSi", "-KZawhnFZLcqFKNwZnSi", "-KZawhnFZLcqFKNwZnSi", "-KZawxBSAwL-lbi7dF-h", "-KZawxBSAwL-lbi7dF-h", "-KZawxBSAwL-lbi7dF-h", "-KZawxBSAwL-lbi7dF-h", "-KZawxBgz8k7v8-fKpDV", "-KZawxBgz8k7v8-fKpDV", "-KZawxBgz8k7v8-fKpDV", "-KZawxBgz8k7v8-fKpDV" ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: If those are uid's created by Firebase (or childByAutoId), they will always be unique and never duplicated. In what condition would you have duplicate user ids? Also, what's the expected behavior? @Frankvanpuffelen has a super snappy answer and while it will 'prevent' duplicates, if you somehow manage to have a duplicate it would overwrite what's there i.e. if you are writing a node -KZawhnFZLcqFKNwZnSi: false it will just overwrite the node in the answer changing the value from true to false. Do you actually want Firebase to error if it's a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to model is a set: a collection of unique entries.

What you've modeled is an array: a sequence of non-unique entries.

The simplest and best solution is to change your data model to actually reflect a set. The closest you can get to that in Firebase is:

```
"sList" : {
    "-KZawgegLrIyq9h6GSf8" : {
      "name" : "Test",
      "users" : { 
        "-KZawhnFZLcqFKNwZnSi": true, 
        "-KZawxBSAwL-lbi7dF-h": true, 
        "-KZawxBgz8k7v8-fKpDV": true
      }
    }
  }
```

With such a set-like structure, duplicates are automatically prevented by the data structure itself. You won't need to write security rules for that.